# JFormattedTextField text disappears

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

If the focus is lost on that JFormattedTextField the text disappears. I don't know why...
I hope anybody of you will see my error. And it seems, that the method classduration will not finish, or not called.....although i don`t get any Exception. This is very weird to me.

```
classdurationField = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("###"));
    classdurationField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if(classdurationField.getText() != null & !classdurationField.getText().equals("   "))
            {
                classduration();
                if(firstopening) checkifallinserted();
            }
        }
    });
    classdurationField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                if(classdurationField.getText() != null & !classdurationField.getText().equals("   "))
                {
                    classduration();
                    if(firstopening) checkifallinserted();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    panel.add(classdurationField, "cell 2 9,growx");
    classdurationField.setColumns(10);
```

and classdurarion:

```
public void classduration()
{
    try {
        String temp = classdurationField.getText();
        temp = temp.trim();
        fkSchedule.changeclassduration(Integer.parseInt(temp));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

//Edit: The Formatted Textfield is appering and visible etc. JUST the Text disappears

*Should I post the whole code (Its much....)??*

Comment: You are aware that `JFormattedTextField` has a `getValue` method which returns you the parsed value, so no need to reparse it yourself

Comment: Are you using `tag:MigLayout`? Did you `pack()` your `Window`?

Comment: I am using tag:MigLayout....I think I explained sth. wrong....

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).